# Regular expression to find all words which starts with white space and ends with white space

Tags: c#, regex, search, whitespace

I need to find words in a string with starting and ending white space. I am finding issues while searching white spaces. However, I could achieve the below. Starts and ends with `@@`. Any help with whitespaces will be great.

```
string input = "@@12@@ @@13@@";             
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, @"@@\b\S+?\b@@"))                
{
   messagebox.show(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: i have this "(\\$\\w+) " which looks for words starting with $ and ending with space. But i need words starting with and ending with space.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) doc:

```
// Define a regular expression for repeated words.
    Regex rx = new Regex(@"\b(?<word>\w+)\s+(\k<word>)\b",
      RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\s+(?=</)
```

is that expression you're after. It means one or more white-space characters followed by

Comment: i get unrecognized escape sequence. If i use @"\s+(?=</)" then its not doing the search.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is betetr to use `string.Split()` instead of `Regex`:

```
var wordsArray = s.Split(new []{' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

it is better to avoid regex if you can achieve the same result easyer with standard string methods.

Comment: i dont want to remove white spaces. i want to search for words with starting and ending spaces.

Answer (score 0):

i cant exactly get what is in your mind but i hope this code can help you:

string[] ha = input.Split(new[] { '@' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);